# HIbernate Tools org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jdbc

My hibernate.cfg.xml is as follow:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="TestSessionFactory">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">!QAZ2wsx</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Testing</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

In Hibernate Configurations tab, I choose Session Factory and then error as follow:

> !ENTRY org.hibernate.eclipse.console 4 4 2019-07-13 01:20:30.359
>   !MESSAGE Problems while creating sessionfactory
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.hibernate.eclipse.console 4 150 2019-07-13 01:20:30.359
>   !MESSAGE org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
>   !STACK 0
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
>       at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_4_3.internal.ConfigurationFacadeImpl.buildTargetSessionFactory(ConfigurationFacadeImpl.java:19)
>       at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractConfigurationFacade.buildSessionFactory(AbstractConfigurationFacade.java:170)
>       at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$5.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:284)
>       at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
>       at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
>       at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(ConsoleConfiguration.java:279)
>       at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazySessionFactoryAdapter.getChildren(LazySessionFactoryAdapter.java:43)
>       at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:98)
>       at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:219)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:285)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2431)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:656)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2440)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2103)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1950)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1162)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:735)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
>       ... 23 more
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.hibernate.eclipse.console 4 150 2019-07-13 01:20:30.360
>   !MESSAGE org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
>   !STACK 0
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
>       at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_4_3.internal.ConfigurationFacadeImpl.buildTargetSessionFactory(ConfigurationFacadeImpl.java:19)
>       at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractConfigurationFacade.buildSessionFactory(AbstractConfigurationFacade.java:170)
>       at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$5.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:284)
>       at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
>       at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
>       at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(ConsoleConfiguration.java:279)
>       at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazySessionFactoryAdapter.getChildren(LazySessionFactoryAdapter.java:43)
>       at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:98)
>       at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:219)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:285)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2431)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:656)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2440)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2103)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1950)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1162)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:735)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
>       ... 23 more
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.hibernate.eclipse.console 4 150 2019-07-13 01:20:30.361
>   !MESSAGE com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
>   !STACK 0
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:285)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2431)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:656)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2440)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2103)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1950)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1162)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:735)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
>       at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_4_3.internal.ConfigurationFacadeImpl.buildTargetSessionFactory(ConfigurationFacadeImpl.java:19)
>       at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractConfigurationFacade.buildSessionFactory(AbstractConfigurationFacade.java:170)
>       at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$5.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:284)
>       at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
>       at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
>       at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(ConsoleConfiguration.java:279)
>       at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazySessionFactoryAdapter.getChildren(LazySessionFactoryAdapter.java:43)
>       at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:98)
>       at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:219)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

My sql server database name is Testing, run in my local PC, username=sa password=!QAZ2wsx
Server name is KEI-PC\SQLEXPRESS
I download mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar and I can see the class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class in  my project Referenced Libraries,

So what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, find finally, the port using is 65064, not default 1433.
So the correct hibernate.cfg.xml should be as follow:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="TestSessionFactory">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">!QAZ2wsx</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:65064;databaseName=Testing</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: It could also mean that your SQL Server instance is using a dynamic port, which could it mean it will use a different port after a restart.

Comment: Oh, then how to fix it to use default port 1433?

Comment: In the Sql Server Configuration Manager, properties of TCP/IP protocol of your instance.